# Laravel 5.4 User Profile NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am creating a user profile that allows him to modify his information here is the code

```
class ProfilesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('content.profil');
    }

    public function editProfile($id)
    {   
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('content.edit', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function updateProfile(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->nom = $request->input('nom');
        $user->prenom = $request->input('prenom');
        $user->adresse = $request->input('adresse');
        $user->code_postal = $request->input('code_postal');
        $user->ville = $request->input('ville');
        $user->pays = $request->input('pays');
        $user->num_tele = $request->input('num_tele');

        $user->save();
        return redirect('/profil');

    }
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>'auth'], function(){
  Route::get('/profil', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profil');
  Route::get('/content', 'ProfilesController@editProfile')->name('profil.edit');
  Route::post('/content', 'ProfilesController@updateProfile')->name('profil.update');
});
```

the view folder tree looks like

```
view/content/profil.blade.php
view/content/edit.blade.php
```

the problem is that the routes are defined but it shows me this error message:

```
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
```

I don't know where the problem exists exactly and
thanks in advance

Comment: What url do you access it ?

Comment: my url is :<a href="{{ url('content/'.Auth::user()->id.'/editProfile') }}">

Comment: http url you use. for instance `http://localhost/project/profile`. I want know what url do you use when you see this exception !

Comment: http://localhost:8000/content/1/editProfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared to your routes (`web.php`) and what you want, this is what your `web.php` file should be

```
  Route::group(['middleware' =>'auth'], function(){
         Route::get('/profil', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profil');
         Route::get('/content/{id}/editProfile', 'ProfilesController@editProfile')->name('profil.edit');
         Route::post('/content/{id}', 'ProfilesController@updateProfile')->name('profil.update');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer it was helpful

Comment: Happy that this help you !

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `profil.edit` route to `/content/{id}/editProfile` and `profil.update` in the same way.

And if you have named routes try to use `route()` helper instead of `url()` to generate url's, it's cleaner are more universal.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer it was helpful